# Last Solr request takes a lot of time

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am experiencing a problematic behavior with Solr 4.0 BETA.

I have an application sending a few parallel requests thanks to `solrj` to my Solr server. Everything is fine and the response times are excellent, but *sometimes*, one request takes a lot of time.

Most of the results are cached in Solr and therefore when observing the elapsed times and actual Solr response times in my application, I see:

```
resquest1: solr: 1ms, elapsed: 150ms
resquest2: solr: 0ms, elapsed: 160ms
resquest3: solr: 3ms, elapsed: 100ms
resquest4: solr: 12ms, elapsed: 20ms
resquest5: solr: 3ms, elapsed: 50000ms
```

The problem is that `50000ms` request which slows down all my app! It is actually even slower than the time needed for Solr to compute the search when it is not cached. It often happens on the last request, as if some buffer was waiting to be flushed.

Is that a common problem and where does it come from? What can I do to avoid such pitfall?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're using BETA, have you tried to look for bugzilla or something?

Comment: I have founs nothing on that matter. I am going to post it on the Solr forum too, but I was wonrdering if anybody on SO already faced the same issue.

Comment: This could be a garbage collection pause on the Solr side, or even your side. If you can directly observe such a request, try and get thread dumps on both sides to see what the applications are doing, or plug JVisualVM (with the VisualGC plugin, preferably) on them to observe what's happening.